Prevent killing of android process when app is in background
I am stuck in a situation where user goes to capture image to set in an image view in an activity but as soon as user returns after capturing image, activity gets restarted.
Same case happens when user sets an image in one image view and app goes to background. when user comes back to the activity, it would be already restarted and the image which was set previously, gets removed.
I have checked my code and there is nothing to do with any code. I can see the log of android process is being ended and re-started when coming back to activity.
Is there any way to prevent android system from destroying or restarting that activity?
I have already tried using android:persistent="true" in manifest file. I can't use foreground service to keep app alive because app doesn't require to do so.
I have gone through so many questions and answers but nothing helped.
Thank you in advance.
Update
Thank you clarification. I am aware that android killing processes is normal and expected behaviour but I can't persist image anywhere because there is some background process related to selected image before setting it into image view. That's the reason I want to prevent the process to be killed in background.

"Is there any way to prevent android system from destroying or restarting that activity?" -- no. That is because it is not "destroying or restarting the activity" -- it is terminating your process. Terminating background processes to free up system RAM has been part of Android since the beginning.

I think you're approaching it from wrong direction. You have to actually persist selected images somewhere (cache files perhaps), because app process being stopped in background is perfectly normal and expected behavior of OS, especially when "heavy" applications like camera enter the foreground. I will agree though that having your activity die after starting another activity for result is a mess.

As you've been told, you cannot prevent the killing of your activity / process. What you can do is better explain you use case and maybe we can offer alternatives. Like what does "some background process" mean? What activities are involved in this flow? Are you interacting with other apps? How do you start the image capture? How do you handle the result? Etc, etc.
